# set my puzzle preview image,make my puzzle parts scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

in below screenshot my preview image under some part's of puzzle.

[image: Screen shot Image]

My problem is i want to scroll my puzzle part's of below preview image, but it couldn't scroll, because of my preview is a one part of canvas.

I have tried solution like:
(1) create New child canvas for that
(2)Create New canvas and give position :absolute
(3)Add z-index in same canvas in Preview image but still same problem

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you're saying your previously drawn preview image is still unnecessarily on the canvas ... then `clearRect` the canvas before drawing your puzzle pieces. If the preview is an actual img element then use CSS to hide that offending preview.

Comment: @markE .. i want to arrange my image part on ghost part .And ghost image not clear because this is for my hint.

Comment: 1. Clear the canvas, 2. DrawImage your hint-ghost-preview image, 3. Draw your puzzle pieces, 4. Repeat #1-3 whenever moving a puzzle piece.

Comment: It is unfair for you to ask us to review 3000+ lines of code. Stackoverflow requires you to give us [Minimal, Complete & Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code to review.  I understand it's difficult to do that when your project has grown to 3000+ lines, but that's the way Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set your image preview in  `img`  tag and apply style it  `pointer-events: none;`